# AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm making a program to generate an encrypted qr from the message and password provided, but it keeps on returning the same error.

I tried passing the value to other variables

main.py

```
from tkinter import *
import crypt

root=Tk()
root.title("QR Crypt")
root.geometry("800x600+0+0")

heading = Label(root, text="QR Code Encrypt", font=("arial",54,"bold"), fg="steelblue").pack()
label1 = Label(root, text="MESSAGE: ", font=("arial",24,"bold"), fg="black").place(x=10,y=200)
label2 = Label(root, text="PASSWORD: ", font=("arial",24,"bold"), fg="black").place(x=10,y=300)
message = StringVar()
entry_box = Entry(root, textvariable=message, width=80, bg="lightgreen").place(x=280, y=210)
passwd = StringVar()
entry_box = Entry(root, textvariable=passwd, width=30, bg="lightgreen").place(x=280, y=310)

def generate_qr():
    crypt.crypt_f(passwd,message)
    canvas = Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)
    canvas.pack()
    img = PhotoImage(file="myqr.svg")
    canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=img)

work = Button(root, text="Generate", width=30, height=5, bg="lightblue", command=generate_qr).place(x=250,y= 400)

mainloop()
```

---

crypt.py

```
import base64
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import qrcode

def crypt_f(password_provided,message_rcvd):
    password = password_provided.encode()
    salt = b'\x8f\x9f3\xf1V\\\n:\xa5\x87h\x9e*\xd1\xc4\xda\xa9.\x96\xfc/\xa9\xb4\x0e\xc8wD\x9d\xee\xeb\xb1E'
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        length=32,
        salt=salt,
        iterations=100000,
        backend=default_backend()
)
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))

    f = Fernet(key)
    encrypted = f.encrypt(message_rcvd)
    qrcode.qr_ready(encrypted)
```

---

qrcode.py

```
from pyqrcode import *

def qr_ready(qr_rcvd):
    toqr=qr_rcvd
    qrcode = create(toqr)
    qrcode.svg("myqr.svg",scale=10)
```

I expect it to return the QR code in another canvas but it is returning the error:

> AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'encode'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main.py

```
from tkinter import *
import crypt
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import time

root=Tk()
root.title("QR Crypt")
root.geometry("800x600+0+0")

heading = Label(root, text="QR Code Encrypt", font=("arial",54,"bold"), fg="steelblue").pack()
label1 = Label(root, text="MESSAGE: ", font=("arial",24,"bold"), fg="black").place(x=10,y=200)
label2 = Label(root, text="PASSWORD: ", font=("arial",24,"bold"), fg="black").place(x=10,y=300)
message = StringVar()
passwd = StringVar()
entry_box1 = Entry(root, textvariable=message, width=80, bg="lightgreen").place(x=280, y=210)
entry_box2 = Entry(root, textvariable=passwd, width=30, bg="lightgreen").place(x=280, y=310)

def generate_qr():
    crypt.crypt_f(passwd.get(), message.get())
    time.sleep(2)
    canvas = Canvas(root, width = 650, height = 650)
    canvas.pack()
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("myqr.png"))
    canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=img)


work = Button(root, text="Generate", width=30, height=5, bg="lightblue", command=generate_qr).place(x=250,y= 400)

mainloop()
```

qrcode.py

```
from pyqrcode import *

def qr_ready(qr_rcvd):
    toqr=qr_rcvd
    qrcode = create(toqr)
    qrcode.png("myqr.png",scale=10)
```

crypt.py

```
import base64
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import qrcode

def crypt_f(password_provided,message_rcvd):
    password = password_provided.encode()
    messge = message_rcvd.encode()
    salt = b'\x8f\x9f3\xf1V\\\n:\xa5\x87h\x9e*\xd1\xc4\xda\xa9.\x96\xfc/\xa9\xb4\x0e\xc8wD\x9d\xee\xeb\xb1E'
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        length=32,
        salt=salt,
        iterations=100000,
        backend=default_backend()
)
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))

    f = Fernet(key)
    encrypted = f.encrypt(messge)
    qrcode.qr_ready(encrypted)
```

Answer (score 0):

StringVar is a custom class, not string. Use get method to retrieve its value as string, like:

```
crypt.crypt_f(passwd.get(), message.get())
```

Comment: Thanks, i completely forgot to use get() and also to convert the message in bytes..

Comment: do you have any suggestion as to how to display the generated qr image as it's showing blank however it does show up the image in a different python file

Comment: Try with xbm as in this example: https://pythonhosted.org/PyQRCode/rendering.html#xbm-rendering

Comment: still the same issue it just shows the same white box and nothing else

Comment: Argh, I forgot, you should make a global reference to an image in Tkinter as the garbage collector cleans it otherwise; do either `canvas.img = PhotoImage(file="myqr.svg")` (ugly as f***) or move the definition `img = PhotoImage()` below `entry_box` assignment and then in your function set the actual image by, afaik, `img.config(file="myqr.svg")`.